# Can't translate inside an HTML canvas

Tags: html, canvas, html5-canvas

I have a HTML canvas and I'd like to scroll the current content to the right by 1 pixel each time I add an new pixel on the left. Basically creating a drawing chart effect

```
function draw()
{
    ctx.save();
    y += Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) - 5);
    ctx.fillStyle = 'blue';
    ctx.translate(1, 0);
    ctx.restore();
    ctx.fillRect(0,y,3,3);

    window.requestAnimationFrame(draw);
}

// init canvas
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3)';
ctx.fillRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);

var y = 0;
draw();
```

For some reason I don't get any visual output on the canvas

Comment: You should restore after you draw otherwise your translate has no effect

Comment: @trker I tried but it doesn't scroll, please try it

Comment: Yes it only draws one line because you call draw() once. Did you try calling draw() with a timeout or loop?

Comment: @trker look closely at the function draw, the last line is: `window.requestAnimationFrame(draw);` that is the callback creating a loop, read more about it here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame

Comment: You're right, I forgot how requestanimframe worked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not clear what you are trying to do with the save and restores...
On the code below I removed them and simplified your code to just print a line

```js
function draw() {
  y += Math.sin(y*23);
  ctx.fillStyle = 'blue';
  ctx.translate(1, 0);
  ctx.fillRect(0, y++, 3, 3);
  window.requestAnimationFrame(draw);
}

// init canvas
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
var y = 0;
draw();
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

---

But you can have this same effect without the translate just by incrementing the x coordinates:

```js
function draw() {
  y += Math.sin(y*23);
  ctx.fillStyle = 'red';
  ctx.fillRect(x++, y++, 3, 3);
  window.requestAnimationFrame(draw);
}

// init canvas
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
var y = 0; x = 0;
draw();
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

---

But if all you need is a nice looking chart you should look into chartjs:
https://www.chartjs.org/samples/latest/